# Get UserID for Current User using Devise/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I, a rails newbie, am currently trying to get the User ID from the current Devise session, and I am having a bit of trouble.

I have this in my controller now:

```
def index
  @currentUser = current_user.id
end
```

And I want to make a simple if statement to show/hide fields in my form.

```
<% if @currentUser === @product.user_id %>
          <%= link_to "Back", products_path %>
          <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>
          <%= link_to "Delete", product_path(@product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
      <% else %>
          <span></span>
<% end %>
```

I have a feeling my syntax in defining my currentUser variable is bad, but I have no idea how to fix this. There were a few similar questions on Stack, but none of them really applied to me or helped me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see a few problems here

```
def index
  @currentUser = current_user.id
end
```

Other than what @HolyMoly already commented, you should use underscore and not camelcase, if `current_user` is nil here, `.id` will fail on it, resulting in an exception.

Second, you are checking "ability" by comparing values of ids, I would change your code to do this

```
<% if allow_product_delete?(@product) %>
```

In a helper

```
def allow_product_delete?(product)
  return false unless current_user
  @product.user_id == current_user.id
end
```

if you are using devise `current_user` exists in controller and views, you don't need to define it as an instance variable, it's already defined as a controller method on all actions (by default). so by calling `current_user` in your views you are done.

If a user is not logged in, `current_user` will be nil, you always have to prepare for this and protect against it.

Last, I would look into ability gems (cancan or cancancan), those provide a very nice DSL for dealing with what you were trying here.

Answer (score 3):

Have you set it up to actually be able to user `current_user` ? 
in your code you have :

`@currentUser = current_user.id`

But where was current_user defined? I haven't used Devise but with sessions you could define the value of current_user with a helper method (you may be able to also do it right there in the sessions_controller #create method), like this:

```
 def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

then throughout your app you could use `current_user.id` or `current_user.name` or whatever you needed.

So while sessions is not Devise, I hope this helps .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ruby like undescored_rather_than camelCased style.

Secondly, you need two equal signs instead of three. `@currentUser == @product.user_id` should work

At third, you don't need to compare integer ids, you can compare models, something like that:

```
<% if current_user == @product.user %>
  <%= link_to "Back", products_path %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", product_path(@product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

Please note that I omitted the `@` in `current_user` method, because `current_user` is helper for devise, else I removed unnecessary `<% else %>` (in my opinion)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.
I tried this out, but it didn't work out, so I wanted to see exactly what is being compared, and printed out `<%= current_user %>`, and got `#<User:0x00000006e5e2e0>`.
Does this have to do with what you said about comparing models instead of integer id's?

Comment: @aishaq11 it's normal situation - this is representing of `Object` class with it's unique id.  Try out something like `<%= current_user.id %>` and `<%= product.user_id %>` at the same rendering. Does id values same?

Answer (score 1):

You should use current_user for this. You can do it everywhere in project. No needs to define variable @currentUser or etc.

You can compare like models

```
if current_user == @product.user
```

that is the equivalent to

```
if current_user.id == @product.user.id
```

In some cases you can use

```
if current_user.id == @product.user_id
```

This prevent extra sql query to load user model

If you are using Devise for authorization and you need control access for actions you should see (maybe use) gem https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

> https://github.com/airbnb/ruby will help you to stay in tune ;)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing IDs is not the best practice for Rails. If you have previously set up the associations correctly, then you don't need to make a comparison between IDs. For example:

```
User
has_many :group_events

GroupEvent
belongs_to :user
```

In this scenario, instead of comparing IDs, you can directly compare with association:

```
Bad
@group_event.user_id == current_user.id

Good
@group_event.user == current_user
```